# Is it possible to 'import * from DIRECTORY', then somehow (anyhow) iterate over the loaded modules?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

Let me explain the use case...

In a simple python web application framework designed for Google App Engine, I'd like to have my models loaded automatically from a 'models' directory, so all that's needed to add a model to the application is place a file user.py (for example), which contains a class called 'User', in the 'models/' directory.

Being GAE, I can't read from the file system so I can't just read the filenames that way, but it seems to me that I must be able to 'import * from models' (or some equivalent), and retrieve at least a list of module names that were loaded, so I can subject them to further processing logic.

To be clear, I want this to be done WITHOUT having to maintain a separate list of these module names for the application to read from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read from the filesystem in GAE just fine; you just can't *write* to the filesystem.

`from models import *` will only import modules listed in `__all__` in `models/__init__.py`; there's no automatic way to import all modules in a package if they're not declared to be part of the package. You just need to read the directory (which you can do) and `__import__()` everything in it.

Comment: "no way" is an exaggeration. In the last couple of days I answered about code that successfully loaded every `.py` in a package as a module to forcefully build a test suite. It was ugly, but fiddling with `__file__` and `__import__` did it.

Comment: @Apalala: right; I was responding to the OP's belief that this needed to be done without actually reading the directory to list the files. Edited for clarity--this is what I was getting at with my first sentence and I never finished the thought.

Comment: I was completely wrong about not being able to read from the file system, which obviously makes things a lot easier. Thanks very much for that clarification.

Comment: Of course, just because you _can_ do it doesn't mean you _should_. Best practice is to add the modules to the package's `__all__`, or import them individually.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained in the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), you cannot load all `.py` files from a directory unless you list them manually in the list named `__all__` in the file `__init__.py`.  One of the reasons why this is impossible is that it would not work well on case-insensitive file systems -- Python would not know in which case the module names should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying that I'm not familiar with Google App Engine, but the following code demonstrates how to import all python files from a directory. In this case, I am importing files from my 'example' directory, which contains one file, 'dynamic_file.py'.

```
import os
import imp
import glob

def extract_module_names(python_files):
    module_names = []
    for py_file in python_files:
        module_name = (os.path.basename(py_file))[:-3]
        module_names.append(module_name)
    return module_names

def load_modules(modules, py_files):
    module_count = len(modules)
    for i in range(0, module_count):
        globals()[modules[i]] = imp.load_source(modules[i], py_files[i])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    python_files = glob.glob('example/*.py')
    module_names = extract_module_names(python_files)
    load_modules(module_names, python_files)
    dynamic_file.my_func()
```

Also, if you wish to iterate over these modules, you could modify the load_modules function to return a list of the loaded module objects by appending the 'imp.load_source(..)' call to a list.

Hope it helps.